# Usar o mesmo disco para 2 VMs no Azure

Tags: wordpress, redes, microsoft-azure, mvvm

Estou com 2 Vms(Ubuntu 15.10) e um load balancer na porta 80 para equilibrar e distribuir o acesso a elas. Nessas Vms eu irei utilizar uma aplicação em Wordpress, porém gostaria de saber como eu compartilho um disco entre essas duas Vms para que ambas possam acessar o mesmo local da pasta *uploads* do wordpress..

Já criei um novo disco e anexei a uma das Vm, porém ao tentar anexar na outra o seguinte erro é gerado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo segue o diagrama da implementação que estou tentando fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode fazer isso, ao menos dessa forma.
Anexar um disco à uma VM é como conectar esse disco na entrada SATA da máquina, não há como compartilhar isso.

O que vc pode fazer é:

1. Criar uma 3a VM, anexar um segundo disco e usar o compartilhamento de arquivos do Windows.
2. Usar Azure Storage, existe [plug-ins wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/windows-azure-storage/) para usar o Storage

Assim suas máquinas irão realmente compartilhar do mesmo storage de arquivos.